# NGINX server directives to reach an API

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have a LEMP server and I'm looking to install RespondCMS (http://respondcms.com/documentation/install-on-digital-ocean). I'm running into some difficulties with the mod_rewrite section for an API. I've tried several iterations but have been unable to get it to show an "API works" message that indicates the PHP app is working. I get a 404. Thus far, I have settled on the following set-up in my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/. I'm thinking it's not accessing the /api folder correctly. Any help in understanding how it's all interacting and how to make it work is appreciated.

```
app.domain.com
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.domain.com;

    root /srv/www/domain_app/app;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/respond.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/respond.error.log;


    location /api/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /api/dispatch.php$args;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /srv/www;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

}





domain.com
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /srv/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the pathname to `dispatch.php`?

Comment: It's /srv/www/domain_app/app/api/dispatch.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL `http://app.domain.com/api/dispatch.php` is processed by the `location ~ \.(hh|php)$` block. And that block seems to be configured (reasonably) correctly.

You should move `include fastcgi_params;` above any `fastcgi_param` directive to avoid the latter being inadvertently overridden. And the `fastcgi_index` directive is redundant in this context.

Both the `location /` and `location /api/` blocks have issues. The `alias` directive is unnecessary and wrong. All three locations inherit their `root` from the outer `server` block. You should delete both `alias` directives.

In your `try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.php /api/dispatch.php$args;` statement, the `$uri.php` element will cause the PHP file to be downloaded rather than executed. Only the last element of a `try_files` directive can take an action that is not processed within the same location block. If you really need to execute extension-less PHP URIs and have a default PHP URI too, you will probably need to use a named location.

A useful resource for all `nginx` directives is [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/dirindex.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help Richard. I updated my config with your suggestions, but still no dice. I removed the $uri.php (though I would like extension-less URIs) to see if it made a difference.  Checking my error log I get this: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: `"PHP message: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'DEFAULT_LANGUAGE' (T_STRING)` in /srv/www/domain_app/app/setup.php on line 21".

Comment: I fixed my PHP error. I had a small mistake when I reinstalled the LEMP setup.

Comment: It works now :D! It was due to PHP errors and not NGINX. So ecstatic, thank you so much for everything.